# Keycloak:How to include `scope` in client credentials grant type?

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak

Using client credentials grant type, the `scope` field is always empty . When I use the password grant type, scopes are well included in the token. Is it normal or do I have other settings to do?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Example of token:

```
{
    "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJXRU5HN1FJc0JiaXpQY1EyY2xqd0tCeXctRGtDdmZFMWdFck4wNWRBc2JBIn0.eyJqdGkiOiIyMDE1NjQxNS03ZDEzLTQwYmYtYTZkZS0xM2E1MjdjOGQzN2IiLCJleH-AQ9euycL3VHQDuesKib9DiShXXm_bVH7WHnWw1URtY1hrBOLQ2hUnFu-C9i66v9QcbvCxcEXYE6drIyAlxk9CEvQN6nKY7rzhpVHa4Kgc_FQ1-0MKmZydZp6Iu1EKngzTq4PxCtza4Lo5nuw9MYd-Vu23fJBfd55M4a8NVl09_yuvYJ95YVEWhBdw1bhd",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "refresh_expires_in": 1800,
    "refresh_token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICI2OGUwNjRiNC0yOTA3LTRmYjYtYTA5MC1mOTM0CJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjgxODAvYXV0aC9yZWFsbXMvY2hpY293YSIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHA6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6ODE4MC9hdXRoL3JlYWxtcy9jaGljb3dhIiwic3ViIjoiNWJlNWE4YjYtMzAzYi00ZWY4LTk5NzEtYjhmMjdjMjE0MDM3IiwidHlwIjoiUmVmcmVzaCIsImF6cCI6InVpc2VydmljZSIsImF1dGhfdGltZSI6MCwic2Vzc2lvbl9zdGF0ZSI6ImUzYj",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "not-before-policy": 1582091643,
    "session_state": "e3b2d2d1-79b2-4e20-8f74-640ee778c1ec",
    "scope": ""
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found why the scope is not included, but it seems strange how Keycloak ties `Client Scopes` to `Roles`.

The reason is, if we have affected some roles to the related scope (we can affect roles to a scope under `Client Scopes > select our scope > Scope` tab) and the service account of our client does not have one of those roles, the scope is not added when we request a token with the client credentials grant type.

I did a test with the password grant type and the result is the same, the `scope` is empty if the user does not have one of the roles affected to the scope.

I am a bit surprised about this behaviour, why that strong coupling between Roles and Client Scopes? What I would expected is to always include client scope in any case but not include user/client roles if they are not affected to the scope.